# A word for a temporary job position?

Tags: single-word-requests

Regarding a job position which:

- Does not seek to replace someone else;
- It's not about a new employee;
- The person is entitled to work as the Chief/Head of the Department with the command of the CEO, to see how this person will handle this position for a certain period of time until entitled permanently or not at all.

I don't want to use the term "temporary", nor "interim", which is used in times of turmoil.

Can you suggest a more appropriate term given the situation above?

Comment: Your first two criteria seem to be contradictory. How can you have a new position or role without replacing someone or getting a new employee? Are you trying to find a title for an existing employee?

Comment: Will this person be cooking? If not, you probably don't mean "chef". Perhaps "head of the department"?

Comment: "Interim" is not exclusively used in times of turmoil. In fact, it doesn't have that connotation to me at all. It just means "temporary" or "provisional". I don't see anything wrong with using it in this case. Of course, if you don't like it, I agree that Chenmunka's suggestion of "acting" would also be suitable.

Comment: I assume you meant 'Chief', but I can't fix your typo. 'Chef' is a professional cook, unless we're speaking German...

Comment: I agree. Both "interim" and "acting" are fine and do not have any negative connotations (as far as I know). I can see what you mean about thinking that one is more "negative" by association like "president" versus "chairman," but honestly, having lived and grown up in two countries with "presidents," I can't say it'd be that much worse than living in a country with a "chairman" :D.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Such a person is said to be [*Acting*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acting&t=crmtb01) in the position.

An *Acting Manager* is someone with all the powers of a Manager but is not formally or permanently assigned to the position.

The word can be applied to any post or rank.  It is used in the military for someone temporarily promoted in the field - for example to replace an incapacitated officer.

If the person may either later be removed from the post or formally assigned to it.  In the latter case, the [*acting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acting_(law)) prefix is removed.

Comment: _Acting Manager_ also suggests (but not as an absolute) that the person was already an employee in a non-manager role.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Out of all the comments, sounds the more appropriate one.

Comment: Note: "Acting" has similar, and with much legalistic review concerning the role of [Acting President, US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acting_President_of_the_United_States)

Comment: *Acting* does not include the third component listed in the question: a person may agree to serve as an Acting . . . , without having any aspirations to be appointed to the position permanently.

Answer (score 9):

If it is a position where the employee is to be evaluated after a certain period of time, after which a decision is made as to their continued employment, then **probationary** is what you are looking for.

[Probation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probation_(workplace)):

> In a workplace setting, probation (or probationary period) is a status given to new employees of a company or business. It is widely termed as the Probation Period of an employee. This status allows a supervisor or other company manager to evaluate closely the progress and skills of the newly hired worker, determine appropriate assignments, and monitor other aspects of the employee such as honesty, reliability, and interactions with co-workers, supervisors or customers.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: "Provisional Chief of Department" might work as well.

Comment: It's not a bout a new employee.

Answer (score 2):

How about **detail**?

MW:

> [**detail**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detail):
>   selection of a person or group for a particular task (as in military
>   service)

So, for example, a CEO could **detail** a person to a particular job to see how it works out for both the organization as a whole and for the person. Where I work (not the military), **detail** is the term we use unless a management position is involved, in which case we use **acting**, as suggested by @Chenmunka. However, **acting** typically means "until a vacant titled position is filled permanently"; it does not mean "test run".

Comment: You can't be the "Detail Director of Marketing", though. You could say that Richard has been *detailed* as the Director of Marketing, or that we plan to *detail* Richard as the Director of Marking, but I'm not sure that's the type of phrasing Elly is looking for.

Comment: No, "detail" was not what I was looking for.

Comment: @CodyGray You didn't read my answer carefully.

Comment: @Elly And why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a secondment, which is the term we use when a person temporarily takes up a role in a different department.

Definition from Oxford Dictionary...

> **Secondment**
>
> The temporary transfer of an official or worker to another position or
>   employment.
>
> ‘he spent two years on secondment to the Department of Industry’

Answer (score 0):

"Ad-hoc" also refers to something similar.

Comment: When intended to be an answer, words should be defined and references provided and they should be relevant to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person would be [position] ***[pro tempore](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pro%20tempore)***:

> For the time being

[Merriam-Webster]

A well-known use of this phrase is in American government, with the position of President pro tempore of the United States Senate. They are an elected member if the Senate who presides over it while the Vice President is away. There is no sense of newness or crisis to it, nor are they replacing the Vice President. There isn't a defined period of time that they might be acting in the Vice President's place either; they are just acting in their absence.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is usually reserved for organizations or institutions, **Provisional** could work here.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provisional):

> Definition of provisional
>   :  serving for the time being :  temporary a provisional government